# Associativity of cartesian product and nested ordered n-tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

for 3 sets $A,B,C$ 
is $A\times B \times C = A\times (B\times C) = (A\times B)\times C$
OR to be more specific,
is the ordered pair $((a,b),c)=$ ordered triplet $(a,b,c)=$ ordered pair $(a,(b,c))$?

Wikipedia states-

[image]

in another article on Wikipedia (and many other e-books and pdfs on the web)-
[image]

I think the root of confusion is the nested ordered pairs-

is the ordered pair $((a,b),c)=$ ordered triplet $(a,b,c)=$ ordered pair $(a,(b,c))$?

Please help

Answer (score 3):

The ordered pairs $\big\langle\langle a,b\rangle,c\big\rangle$ and $\big\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle\big\rangle$ are not equal. Formally, an ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ is the set $\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}$, so

$$\big\langle\langle a,b\rangle,c\big\rangle=\left\langle\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\},c\right\rangle=\left\{\left\{\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\}\right\},\left\{\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\},c\right\}\right\}\;,\tag{1}$$

while

$$\big\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle\big\rangle=\left\langle a,\big\{\{b\},\{b,c\}\big\}\right\rangle=\left\{\left\{a\right\},\left\{a,\big\{\{b\},\{b,c\}\big\}\right\}\right\}\;.\tag{2}$$

As the second Wikipedia quotation says, $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times(B\times C)$ are equal if and only if at least one of $A,B$, and $C$ is empty, so that

$$(A\times B)\times C=\varnothing=A\times(B\times C)\;.$$

Note, however, that there is always a very natural bijection $h$ between $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times(B\times C)$, given by

$$h:(A\times B)\times C\to A\times(B\times C):\big\langle\langle a,b\rangle,c\big\rangle\mapsto\big\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle\big\rangle\;,$$

and in most settings it’s both harmless and very convenient to pretend that they’re the same set and ignore the technical, formal difference.

Whether either $\big\langle\langle a,b\rangle,c\big\rangle$ or $\big\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle\big\rangle$ is equal to $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ depends on how the ordered triple has been defined. It is perfectly possible to define ordered $n$-tuples as in the first Wikipedia quotation; if one does, then by definition

$$\langle a,b,c\rangle=\big\langle\langle a,b\rangle,c\big\rangle\;.$$

However, for $n>2$ one can also define ordered $n$-tuples to be functions whose domain is $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. If we adopt that definition, then

$$\langle a,b,c\rangle=\{\langle 0,a\rangle,\langle 1,b\rangle,\langle 2,c\rangle\}\;,$$

the function that sends $0$ to $a$, $1$ to $b$, and $2$ to $c$. Formally this is

$$\left\{\big\{\{0\},\{0,1\}\big\},\big\{\{1\},\{1,b\}\big\},\big\{\{2\},\{2,c\}\big\}\right\}\;,$$

something quite different from the sets in $(1)$ and $(2)$. Once again, though, in most settings it’s a matter of indifference which technical definition of *ordered* $n$-*tuple* we use: the important thing is that an ordered $n$-tuple is an object with $n$ identifiable components, any of which may be equal, whose positions in the object are specified.

Answer (score 1):

Brian M. Scott's answer is 100% correct, at least from the viewpoint of [material set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material+set+theory), which is perhaps the currently dominant paradigm. Let me briefly describe a *different* viewpoint, namely the [structural](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) viewpoint.

According to structuralist philosophy, the appropriate question isn't whether or not the set $(A \times B) \times C$ is *equal* to $A \times (B \times C)$. Rather, we should ask:

1. ("Weak Sameness") Is it true that for all sets $A,B$ and $C$, the sets $(A \times B) \times C$ and $A \times (B \times C)$ are isomorphic?
2. ("Strong Sameness") Is it true that the [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) $\lambda A,B,C : \mathbf{Set},(A \times B) \times C$ is isomorphic to the functor $\lambda A,B,C : \mathbf{Set},A \times (B \times C)$?

The answer to the 1st question is clearly yes, using the function Brian denotes $h$ in his answer. In fact, the answer to the 2nd question also a resounding "YES!"; you can try to prove it yourself, if you want, or else try looking up the proof in any basic [category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) text. If you're interested in this viewpoint, perhaps check out [Sets for mathematics](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpatryshev.com%2Fbooks%2FSets%2520for%2520Mathematics.pdf&ei=IccPVdwwhbryBfetgsAJ&usg=AFQjCNEBcH87CAYm52zAk9Kq_tux3vDoBQ&sig2=ysBq1TND3F1FNoXoTcUPxQ&bvm=bv.88528373,d.dGc) by Lawvere/Rosebrugh, and/or [Categories for the Working Mathematician](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387984038) by Saunders Mac Lane.