# Kuratowski Construction of a Triple

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that the Kuratowski's method to construct an ordered pair from sets is

$⟨a,b⟩=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$

From my reading it appears that the most common way to denote a triple is as a nested ordered pair with the first and second coordinates paired first and then paired with the third coordinate.

$⟨a,b,c⟩=⟨⟨a,b⟩,c⟩$

I was wondering why this is the norm and if there is a fundamental reason a triple can't be a nested ordered pair with the second and third coordinates paired first and then paired with the first coordinate.  For one the underlying Kuratowski set construction of the triple is much simpler and easier.

$⟨⟨a,b⟩,c⟩=\{\{⟨a,b⟩\},\{\{⟨a,b⟩\},\{c\}\}\}=\{\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\},\{\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\},\{c\}\}\}$
$⟨a,⟨b,c⟩⟩=\{\{a\},\{\{a\},\{⟨b,c⟩\}\}\}=\{\{a\},\{\{a\},\{\{b\},\{b,c\}\}\}\}$

I understand from scanning posts here that it fundamentally does not matter since the two nested pair versions are canonically isomorphic and behave identically outside of their set theoretic construction, but still curious why the more complicated version (whose complexity grows further with n-tuples) is more common.  Thanks.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500787/definition-of-the-ordered-triple-a-b-c-according-to-kuratowskis-set-theory)

Comment: You’ve errors in both of your expansions at the end. The first is almost right, but the expansion of $\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle\rangle$ is way off. The two end up being equally complex if done correctly, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202223/associativity-of-cartesian-product-and-nested-ordered-n-tuples/1202259#1202259). One could define it either way; it makes little difference.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry didn't see that answer before posting.  I went through the exercise myself in Word where the equation editor makes it easier to track the plethora of braces by making outer ones much larger.  Despite the typos, still seems like the latter version is simpler but understand it does not fundamentally matter. By the way, is there a typo in the answer you link to.  Maybe I am not interpreting it correctly but shouldn't the {0,1} in the last equation be a {0,a}?  Thanks again.