# Graphing cartesian product of two sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Graph the following cartesian product of sets:

$\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^{2}| x^{2}+y^{2}\le1\}\times[0,1]$

Upon reading the book more closely, it gives the hint that this problem should be graphed in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$.

Now let
$A = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb{R}^{2}| a^{2}+b^{2}\le1\}$
$B = [0,1] = \{c \in \Bbb R|0\le c\le 1\}$

Then
$A \times B = \{(u,v)|u \in A, v \in B\} = \{((a,b),c)|((a,b) \in \Bbb{R^{2}}, a^{2}+b^{2} \le{1}) \land (c \in \Bbb{R},  0 \le c \le 1)\}$.

My best answer right now is that $A \times B$ is a cylinder centered at $(0,0,0)$ and height of 1 unit on the z-axis. The z- axis serves as the orientation and also as an axis of rotation for the cylinder.

I did this by doig the cross product of some "critical test points" between sets $A$ and $B$ and graphing them in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$.

The Points are
$$((0,0),0), ((1,0),0), ((0,1),0), ((-1,0),0), ((0,-1),0)$$
and
$$((0,0),1),((1,0),1), ((0,1),1), ((-1,0),1), ((0,-1),1)$$.

But it would seem that is it that for $a,b,c \in A×B$, $((a,b),c) = (a,b,c)$.

But by this question, [Associativity of cartesian product and nested ordered n-tuples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202223/associativity-of-cartesian-product-and-nested-ordered-n-tuples), the above cannot happen. Can some one explain this to me, please.

Comment: Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. For formatting help, See: [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!

Comment: in what dimension do you visualize this cartesian product?

Comment: I visualize the Cartesian product to be in the two-dimensional plane

Comment: What dimension does the first set have? What dimension does the second set have? What happens when you take the Cartesian product of sets with those dimensions?

Comment: @Popocatepetl112358 your answer is _almost_ correct. The condition "$x^2+y^2\le1$" means that (x,y) must lie inside the circle or on its circumference, but not outside it. [0,1] is simply the line segment of length 1 along the x-axis. Your solution set is therefore the entire right half of the circle.

Comment: H. sapiens rex, do you mean the region on the 2-d plane bounded by the horizontal axis, the vertical axis and the upper right quarter of the circle? The set [0,1] would be part of the upper half of vertical axis.

Comment: ConMan, if by dimension you mean the cardinality of each set, the first set with the "circle" is a subset of RxR and so is the closed interval set [0,1]. Since RxR is uncountably infinite, so should be [0,1] and the first set with the "circle". Since they are subsets of RxR, I would assume they inherit the dimension of RxR, which is dimension 2.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex - $[0,1]$ here is not a line segment along the $x$-axis. The $x$-axis and $y$-axis are both directions in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$. But the $[0,1]$ in the problem is an indepenent direction from either of those.

Comment: Oh, ok. What does the 2-D graph of that look like then?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex - What 2-D graph are you referring to? The question was about the product of a 2-D set with a 1-D set. What makes either of you think that is going to be 2-D?

Comment: @PaulSinclair oh I don't know, the question itself? "Graph the following cartesian product of sets", key word "graph", kiiiinda makes one expect a graph, y'know?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex - You've never seen or done a 3D graph? They didn't look nearly as pretty, but in ye olden dayes, we even did them by hand. This one isn't particularly hard to graph. Just do an ellipse, translate it a bit parallel to the minor axis, connect the apexes of the two ellipses with line segments, erase (or dash) the "back half" of the lower ellipse.

Comment: I think Paul Sinclair is right since the first set is a subset of RxR (2D- plane, but the second set [0,1] is a subset of  R. I let myself think incorrectly that [0,1] was a subset of RxR because of the two numbers 0 and 1 and forgot that it was an interval in the real line. Now I am confused. Would [0,1] be in the horizontal axis of the "circle" set, would [0,1] live in the vertical axis on the "circle set or would it live in it's own independent axis (i.e 3rd dimension)?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is along a third direction.

Comment: I'd say you justify it by $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Graph the following cartesian product of sets:

$\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^{2}|x^{2}+y^{2} \le 1\}×[0,1]$

Let $A = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb{R}^{2}|a^{2}+b^{2} \le 1\}$
$B = [0,1] = \{c \in \Bbb{R}|0\le c \le 1\}$

Then $A×B = \{(u,v)|u \in A,v \in B\} = \{((a,b),c)|((a,b) \in \Bbb{R}^{2},a^{2}+b^{2} \le 1) \land (c \in \Bbb{R},0 \le c \le 1)\}$

My best answer right now is that $A×B$ is a cylinder centered at $(0,0,0)$ and height of 1 unit on the z-axis. The z- axis serves as the orientation and also as an axis of rotation for the cylinder.

I did this by doig the cross product of some "critical test points" between sets $A$ and $B$ and graphing them in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$

The Points are
$((0,0),0),((1,0),0),((0,1),0),((−1,0),0),((0,−1),0)$

and

$((0,0),1),((1,0),1),((0,1),1),((−1,0),1),((0,−1),1)$

This answer addresses the question because I state what the graph should look like in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$.

Although I did not include a graph as I don't know how to include it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).